# check if latest openssh patch provided by RHEL is installed

Tags: rpm, openssh

We have encountered a security threat in one of our **RHEL** servers which says the *SSH server is configured to use Cipher Block Chaining*.

As far as I know, the RHEL systems provide security updates through their RHN satellite which can be achieved just by running the `yum update` command. But, how can I know if the security patch is applied to my RHEL system?

**P.S**: I know the CVE number of the vulnerability/threat/issue.

So my question is, is it possible for me to verify that the RHEL `yum update` command has fixed the bug in my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this with `yum-plugin-security`:

```
--cve  This option includes packages that say they fix a CVE - Common
       Vulnerabilities and Exposures ID (http://cve.mitre.org/about/),
       Eg. CVE-2201-0123.
```

So try:

```
yum --cve <Your CVE here> info updates
```

And you can check the changelog coressponding to the packages to check information about bug fixed:

```
$ rpm -q --changelog openssh | grep -i cve
- change default value of MaxStartups - CVE-2010-5107 - #908707
- merged cve-2007_3102 to audit patch
- fixed audit log injection problem (CVE-2007-3102)
- CVE-2006-5794 - properly detect failed key verify in monitor (#214641)
- CVE-2006-4924 - prevent DoS on deattack detector (#207957)
- CVE-2006-5051 - don't call cleanups from signal handler (#208459)
- use fork+exec instead of system in scp - CVE-2006-0225 (#168167)
```

Comment: Your option really seems good.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes it is possible.**

*CVE is a dictionary of publicly known information security vulnerabilities and exposures.* If we know the CVE number, we can check if RHEL has fixed the threat in our systems by checking the CVE number [here](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/).

So in my case, the CVE number was **CVE-2008-5161**. I checked for the CVE number in the above mentioned link and found that the fix for `openssh` was provided in the package provided by the update of [this](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2009-1287.html) rpm.

So, I ran the query `ssh -V` which gives me the output as,

```
OpenSSH_4.3p2
```

But the above query just returns the version.

However, I need to know if the patch `openssh-4.3p2-36` is applied to my system. The RHEL updates are applied in patches which do not update the package numbers. So, for example, if RHEL 5 systems have the OpenSSH version of 4.3 installed, the updates will not make it to the next 4.4 version but rather fix the same version but in patches. This feature is known as [backporting](https://access.redhat.com/site/security/updates/backporting/?sc_cid=3093) in RHEL. So, for the security threat that I had faced, I need to verify the patch 36 is installed in my system. I can check the same using the command,

```
rpm -qa | grep -i ssh
```

The above command returns me the output as,

```
openssh-askpass-4.3p2-82.el5
libssh2-devel-1.2.7-1.el5.remi
openssh-server-4.3p2-82.el5
libssh2-1.2.7-1.el5.remi
openssh-clients-4.3p2-82.el5
openssh-4.3p2-82.el5
```

This means I have the latest security patch provided by RHEL available in my system.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that Red Hat provides an [online CVE database](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/) that will tell you the specific versions of their software that resolve relevant CVE's.

Comment: @JoelDavis, I have included the link that you have specified in my answer :)

Comment: Damn. Having one of those days I guess. Sorry about that.